# Combine two objects using JsonPath

Tags: json, jsonpath

Suppose I have json like this:

```
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
  },
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "d": 4
  }
]
```

Is it possible to write a [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) which will give me:

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": 4
}
```

The order of the elements in the list is not sure, however the element names I know beforehand. So I thought I could use JsonPath to select all elements with names 'a', 'b', 'c' or 'd' and put them in a single object. However, I now have tried several things and I start to doubt whether what I want is possible.

For example I can select an object which has an element c with:

```
$[?(@.c)]
```

And I can also select just the value of d with something like:

```
$..d
```

But I can not find any way to comebine them into a single object. Is what I want possible with JsonPath or is this a limitation of JsonPath?

Answer (score -1):

I think the appropriate way to do this is to remove the second object and apply the difference between them to the first one:

```
[
  { "op": "remove", "path": "/1" },
  { "op": "add", "path": "/0/d", "value": 4 }
]
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you're OK with polyfilling for IE (it's ES6), use Object.assign:

```
const object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};
const object2 = {
  d: 4
}

const objectMerged = Object.assign({}, object1, object2);

console.log(objectMerged.c);
console.log(objectMerged.d);
```

For full details, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I know this is relatively easy to do programmatically, but I am limited to use JsonPath, so I am really looking for a solution with JsonPath or otherwise have some confirmation that is not possible with JsonPath.

Comment: Spent a little more time looking - I have nothing for you directly in JsonPath. Mind if I ask the reason you're limited to just JsonPath?

Comment: In this case the application is combining outputs of AWS step functions, see: https://states-language.net/spec.html#path